# How does the radius of a pipe correlate to the velocity of air at a gradient of sizes?

Tags: aerodynamics

Suppose your pipe isn't a mere cylinder, but is more like a cone or a solid revolution of an ogive curve. It's standard that a small pipe will force air through it faster, but how do you calculate the velocity of air at any given part of it? Is there also a most optimal shape that maximizes or minimizes the velocity of air as it comes out one end?

Also even though air is coming out faster through a smaller opening, is there less air or the same amount of air coming out per second since some of the air gets squeezed back into itself and moving air has lower pressure which equates to a less dense cross section of less particles?

Comment: If you consider air to be incompressible, which is suprisingly a pretty good approximation if temperature doesn't change, then conservation of mass yields 
$\mathcal{Q}=Const$, which means $v\cdot A = const.$
Velocity and area are inversely proportional.

Comment: So it doesn't matter at all what the shape of the pipe is, it just matters what the cross section of the exit is? Something about that just doesn't seem right. Air might not compress easily, but it swirls around and creates eddies when it moves and creates lower pressure as it moves faster, and if it's not compressible that means the backed up portion is going to push away from itself a lot more quickly when it does become compressed into a smaller exit.

Comment: Turbulent flow is hard to study. A stationary and laminar model is usually right. You can make it a bit more sophisticated if you know $v(r)$, but taking the mean value makes $vA=const$ hold quite good.

Comment: What if temperature does change in something like an adiabatic process?

Comment: I also just notice after all this time and these comments that somehow a site allegedly full of physicists hasn't actually stated a quantitative method to make these calculations, which I find surprising. What is the actual math and information needed to determine the air velocity over a given part of a tube?